# PDF - set password protected print, copy, paste options?

Tags: python, security, pdf, reportlab

I'm looking for a Python library that allows me to set password protected print, copy, paste options on existing PDF files.

### What I tried

I looked at the reportlab pdfencrypt module: this has exactly the options I need, but the open source version is heavily restricted - cant even set a real password, and the license is not an option (over £1000/year) - this will be relatively low volume (< 1000 docs processed per year), and the client is a non-profit organisation

Comment: How concerned are you about security? PDF encryption and use restrictions are easy to break. Keep in mind that about all it takes to circumvent PDF DRM is a google search for 'pdf crack'.

Comment: Yeah, not worried about security - obviously with the tools I'm using it is trivial to decrypt a pdf. However ~ 90% of users wont be bothered to crack, and there is not way to stop those that do want to - apart from enforcing more draconian measures such as creating a paywall etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried The PDF Toolkit, command-line interface (`pdftk`)?

http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

Comment: good point, I'd not looked. pdftk will definitely do the job, but would rather do it in python if possible!
http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-output-enc-strength

Answer (score 7):

You (just like me)  must have thought - WTF is `"-3904"` from Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016018/7797962).

Please get yourself comfortable - I have the answer).

I have found it in the PDF 1.6 reference. You can get it here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/PDFReference16.pdf

The 3.5 section, page number 99:

> 32-bit integer containing a set of flags specifying which access
> permissions should be granted when the document is opened with user
> access. Table 3.20 shows the meanings of these flags. Bit posi­tions
> within the flag word are numbered from 1 (low-order) to 32
> (high-order). A 1 bit in any position enables the corresponding access
> permission. Which bits are meaningful, and in some cases how they are
> interpreted, depends on the security handler’s revision number
> (specified in the encryption dictionary’s R entry).
>
> *Note: PDF integer objects are represented internally in signed twos-complement form. Since all the reserved high-order flag bits in
> the encryption dictionary’s P val­ ue are required to be 1, the value
> must be specified as a negative integer. For exam­ ple, assuming
> revision 2 of the security handler, the value -44 permits printing and
> copying but disallows modifying the contents and annotations.

So, `P` is permission! Please check the table in that document. `-44` is `11010100` in bits representation.

I have made it like this(printing and copying are permitted but modifying the contents and annotations are disallowed):

```
from hashlib import md5

from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF4.generic import NameObject, DictionaryObject, ArrayObject, \
    NumberObject, ByteStringObject
from PyPDF4.pdf import _alg33, _alg34, _alg35
from PyPDF4.utils import b_


def encrypt(writer_obj: PdfFileWriter, user_pwd, owner_pwd=None, use_128bit=True):
    """
    Encrypt this PDF file with the PDF Standard encryption handler.

    :param str user_pwd: The "user password", which allows for opening
        and reading the PDF file with the restrictions provided.
    :param str owner_pwd: The "owner password", which allows for
        opening the PDF files without any restrictions.  By default,
        the owner password is the same as the user password.
    :param bool use_128bit: flag as to whether to use 128bit
        encryption.  When false, 40bit encryption will be used.  By default,
        this flag is on.
    """
    import time, random
    if owner_pwd == None:
        owner_pwd = user_pwd
    if use_128bit:
        V = 2
        rev = 3
        keylen = int(128 / 8)
    else:
        V = 1
        rev = 2
        keylen = int(40 / 8)
    # permit copy and printing only:
    P = -44
    O = ByteStringObject(_alg33(owner_pwd, user_pwd, rev, keylen))
    ID_1 = ByteStringObject(md5(b_(repr(time.time()))).digest())
    ID_2 = ByteStringObject(md5(b_(repr(random.random()))).digest())
    writer_obj._ID = ArrayObject((ID_1, ID_2))
    if rev == 2:
        U, key = _alg34(user_pwd, O, P, ID_1)
    else:
        assert rev == 3
        U, key = _alg35(user_pwd, rev, keylen, O, P, ID_1, False)
    encrypt = DictionaryObject()
    encrypt[NameObject("/Filter")] = NameObject("/Standard")
    encrypt[NameObject("/V")] = NumberObject(V)
    if V == 2:
        encrypt[NameObject("/Length")] = NumberObject(keylen * 8)
    encrypt[NameObject("/R")] = NumberObject(rev)
    encrypt[NameObject("/O")] = ByteStringObject(O)
    encrypt[NameObject("/U")] = ByteStringObject(U)
    encrypt[NameObject("/P")] = NumberObject(P)
    writer_obj._encrypt = writer_obj._addObject(encrypt)
    writer_obj._encrypt_key = key


unmeta = PdfFileReader('my_pdf.pdf')

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.appendPagesFromReader(unmeta)
encrypt(writer, '1', '123')

with open('my_pdf_encrypted.pdf', 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

Please vote, if you liked my answer ;).

Comment: It seems like a user password should be provided. But what needs to be done if I don't want a user password?

Answer (score 3):

Laaate answer, but I wanted to start contributing...

in the pdf.py file, in the encypt() method, change the flag:

```
    # permit everything:
    P = -1
```

to:

```
    # prevent everything:
    P = -3904
```

This will prevent all features beyond simple viewing.  Be sure to pass in a **different** owner password.

Comment: Can you explain? Where is this pdf.py file? Which library are you using ??

Comment: @AbhijithK it's from PyPDF2

Answer (score 0):

[PyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) allows [encrypting](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html#pyPdf.pdf.PdfFileWriter.encrypt-method) PDF files.

Comment: yeah but has no options re: print, copy, paste etc - see:
http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html#pyPdf.pdf.PdfFileWriter.encrypt-method

Comment: You'll probably have to go with command line tools, as @user1202136 suggests, for that. I don't know of any free Python package that does it.