# protect from copying or modifying pdf file with python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, centos7

Looking for a solution to protect a pdf from a viewer to copy from it or modify it's content.

I'm not referring to password protection.

We are using [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/) to `drawImage` and `drawString`, however it seems that the data we are drawing can be copied to clipboard from a standard pdf viewer.

How can I prevent that?
Have checked PDFtk already and this is not an option, since there's a compatibility issue with Centos7 (..that i run), moreover, I prefer a pure python if possible

Comment: What about screenshots? Do you want to block these as well?

Comment: I'll be satisfied with only prevent copying to clipboard. which btw, is possible with some command line tools, but I try to use pure python

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: pdf - set password protected print, copy, paste options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109867/python-pdf-set-password-protected-print-copy-paste-options)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've checked that beforehand and the "flatten" option, seem to be interesting, But I do have couple of issues with it: 1) Im running on Centos 7, while pdftk, has some compatibility issues with it (they are working on it), 2) I really prefer a pure python package, rather than command line

Answer (score -1):

This is a very late reply, but the solution you are looking for is a format called PDF/A.

There is several option underneath, so it is worth reading into it. This literally flattens your PDF and modifies it with additional fields, protecting a user to "copy+paste" the information directly. It anyhow does not protect the document of being send somewhere or screenshots etc..

Ghostscript is supporting this, as one of many.

Comment: Pdf/a is not about copy or modification protection. On the contrary, it is designed to allow access to pdf contents for decades to come. (Conversion to pdf/a indeed sometimes requires flattening content into an image because pdf/a does not allow transparency, but if no transparency is used in a document no such flattening is needed for transformation into pdf/a.)